# Getting error while logging in IBM bluemix using CLI?

Tags: ibm-cloud

While I try to login in IBM bluemix using CLI editor, the connection is getting refused. I am using sydney region. Below is the command which I passed.

```
cf api https://api au-syd.bluemix.net
```

> Error performing request: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: This sounds like the firewall is blocking the connection. Could you check?

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint isn't correct as it is missing a period/full-stop between 'api' and 'au-syd'.

Try:

```
cf api https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net
```

Then you can login with your credentials using:

```
cf login
```